# Is it possible to upgrade an unmanaged package by installing another unmanaged package?

Tags: package-install, package-dependency

I have an unmanaged package with some features for Opportunity. It includes classes, triggers and custom objects.

I'd like to extend that features to Quote and Order. Is it possible to make extension packages that won't conflict with the one already installed?

p.s.: I'd like to avoid the need to make especific classes and custom objects for each package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Unmanaged packages can't be the base for another package, and any conflicting fields, objects, classes, triggers, etc that are conflicting will cause the second package to fail to install.

Answer (score 2):

While it's not quite the same as having an installable package, you can achieve the identical end effect of an upgradeable unmanaged package by using the Metadata API.

When an Unmanaged Package installs in your org, it creates a package in the org just like if you were developing an unmanaged package (look under Setup -> Create -> Packages) and all the package's metadata is linked to the package.  The Metadata API's retrieve method has an attribute, `packageNames`, where you can specify to retrieve the metadata of a named package in the org.

So, if you use the following ant snippet with the Force.com Ant Migration Tool, you can retrieve the source code of the package:

```
  <sf:retrieve 
    username="${sf.username}" 
    password="${sf.password}" 
    serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" 
    retrieveTarget="src" 
    packageNames="UNMANAGED_PACKAGE_NAME_HERE"/>
```

What you'll get is a `src` directory populated with the metadata source of the package.  The package.xml file will have a line:

```
<fullName>UNMANAGED_PACKAGE_NAME_HERE</fullName>
```

What you have now is the source of a package which can be deployed via the Force.com Ant Migration Tool into any org.  When deployed, it will create the Unmanaged Package and link all the package's metadata with the package.  If the Unmanaged Package is already installed in the org, the deploy

You can use this to retrieve declarative changes in an org made on top of an installed Unmanaged Package.  Just make sure you go to Setup -> Create -> Packages and add any new metadata to the package before retrieving.  Then, you can deploy those changes into another org which has the Unmanaged Package installed to effectively "update" the Unmanaged Package.

There's no push upgrade, namespacing, or easy installation UI, but it's a great way to manage moving metadata around between orgs.  Since you're just dealing with Metadata API retrieves and deploys, it's easy to build tooling around this too.

One thing to note is that the deploy will handle adding metadata but not deleting metadata.  So if your new version of the package deletes metadata, you'll have to either manually delete it from the org or use build scripts to handle the delete.  Many of the targets needed for this are available in [CumulusCI](https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/CumulusCI)